# openerp XML RPC search by many2one id

Tags: php, api, odoo, xml-rpc

I'm currently working with XMLRPC API for connecting a website to openerp . The idea is we want to get the latest stock quantity from openerp. Currently i'm using [this connector library](https://github.com/tejastank/openerp-php-connector) . This is the sample data from my openerp api

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [create_date] => 2016-01-26 03:02:29
            [qty] => 6
            [propagated_from_id] => 
            [package_id] => 
            [cost] => 1500000
            [inventory_value] => 9000000
            [lot_id] => 
            [reservation_id] => 
            [id] => 2
            [negative_dest_location_id] => 
            [create_uid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => Administrator
                )

            [display_name] => 17326: 6.0Unit(s)
            [__last_update] => 2016-01-26 03:02:29
            [location_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19
                    [1] => Warehouse 1/Stock
                )

            [company_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => PT. ONE WAY
                )

            [history_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [owner_id] => 
            [write_date] => 2016-01-26 03:02:29
            [write_uid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => Administrator
                )

            [name] => 17326: 6.0Unit(s)
            [product_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2756
                    [1] => [17326]  AEG Vacuum Cleaner Dust Extractor Wet & Dry AP 20
                )

            [packaging_type_id] => 
            [negative_move_id] => 
            [in_date] => 2016-01-26 03:02:29
        )
```

How can i filter that data by product_id

```
[product_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2756
                    [1] => [17326]  AEG Vacuum Cleaner Dust Extractor Wet & Dry AP 20
                )
```

Here is my code

```
$rpc = new OpenERP();

$x = $rpc->login("supermin", "my_site", "my_pass", "http://111.222.33.44:8069/xmlrpc/");

$data = $rpc->searchread(
    array(
        array("model", "=", "product.product"),
        array("module", "=", "sale"),
        array("product_id", "=", "2756"),
    ),
    "stock.quant"
);
```

Any example will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
//... your source
$data = $rpc->searchread(
    array(
        array('model', '=', 'product.product'),
        array('module', '=', 'sale'),
        array('product_id', '=', '2756'),
    ),
    'stock.quant',
    array(), // default
    0, // default
    10, // default
    'product_id DESC' // default value was 'id DESC'
);
```

I did not use *connector lib*, but if we check [searchread() method of OpenERP class](https://github.com/tejastank/openerp-php-connector/blob/master/openerp.class.php) we can see that default `$order = "id DESC"`.

Hope this help you.

Comment: thanks for the code sample , i'm using this code : $data = $rpc->searchread( array( array('product_id', '=', 2756) ),"stock.quant"); Where product_id is actually the variant id of a product, so you must get product variant id first to use in this search filter then you get the stock quant data,

Comment: I not understood. As I see `$model_name = 'stock.quant'`. It means that data will be searched in table `stock_quant`(Odoo object *stock.quant*, default columns we can see in addon **stock**). Here column from **stock.py**: `'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', required=True, ondelete="restrict", readonly=True, select=True)`. How you want to sort data?